# (React-Native) Warning eslint(react-native/no-color-literals)

Tags: react-native, eslint

I have this style in react-native

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
```

but It gives me this eslint warning `Warning eslint(react-native/no-color-literals)`

I tried this styling but it didn't work

```
{
  backgroundColor: BLACK,
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this link](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native/blob/master/docs/rules/no-color-literals.md) to understand the warning.

> When developing UIs, we often find ourselves reusing the same colors in multiple places in the UI. If the colors have to be updated, they likely have to be updated across the board. So it's good practice to store the color definitions in variables instead of hardcoding them inside styles. This rule will detect color properties that have literals (ie strings) as values.

You can either disable this warning on eslint or put the string into a variable.

```
const blackOpa80 = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)'
```

And then:

```
backgroundColor: blackOpa80,
```